# JQuery Mega Menu Full Width Menu Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to css and jquery and have a problem with a menu item. I have a Jquery Mega Menu and I want to have the Attorney Profile menu item be 1 single row instead of the two it is now. Normally I would post code but there just is to much. So I am going to post a link to the actual working site.

**I tried adding fullwidth but no success.**

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#mega-menu-tut').dcMegaMenu({
        rowItems: '1',
        speed: 'fast'
        fullWidth: true
  });
 });
```

**I also tried to modify the css here:**

```
.dcjq-mega-menu ul.menu li .sub li.mega-hdr { /* Sub-menu headers - i.e. 2nd level navigation */
     float: left; /* Float the sub-menus and give them a fixed width to from the mega menu    rows */
     width: 130px; 
     height: 165px;
     margin: 0 2px 7px 2px;
     border: 3px solid #ccc;
}
```

But that just modifies that actual inside menu.

**Here is the active site:** http://gdisinc.com/barker/default.php

Notice if you roll your mouse over Attorney Profiles it will show two rows. How can I make that one row that matches the width of the site which is 960px. Thank you!

**PS: I used this menu system: http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/getting-started/**

Answer (score 1):

You can change the padding on this style

```
.dcjq-mega-menu ul.menu li a
```

to

```
padding:12px 20px;
```

The elements in the have a width based on their content, so reducing font-size for navigation items would work as well. Fixes for such problems are easily found using Chrome's Web Inspector / Firefox's Firebug etc.

Would be probably good to not have the small divider after contact us tab as well. You could achieve this by adding a :last-child class like this:

```
.dcjq-mega-menu ul.menu li:last-child a { background:none; }
```

The problem is that the CSS selector here is not very readable and can lead to very annoying problems later on. If you can, always change such long declarations to a single class:

```
.last-menu-item { background:none; }
```

As well, keep in mind that :last-child is not supported on Internet Explorer < 9.
http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child

Welcome to the world of CSS ... :)

Comment: I still prefer tables much faster personally. But thank you for the suggestions. I did change the padding as you suggested but no good! The changes for contact us worked great tho. Any other suggestions that would work? As per your suggestion I changed this `.dcjq-mega-menu ul.menu li a {
float: left; 
display: block;  
padding: 12px 20px; 
background: url(../images/menubar/bg_red.png) repeat-x 100% 0; 
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; 
text-decoration: none;
}`

Comment: You won't get far tables these days! Nothing you will do in your CSS will be able change that to a single row, the width and height is added by the script after CSS has been read. @disperse answer is right, make sure you are calling the function only in one place with rowItems: '5'. Maybe change it and clear cache; at the moment your site still shows the option set to '3' ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to change the "rowitems" option here:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  $('#mega-menu-tut').dcMegaMenu({
    rowItems: '3',
    speed: 'fast'
  });
});
```

If you change it to '5' it should display all of the items on the same row.  Take a look at the examples:

http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/examples/

It doesn't look like there is a way to configure this effect per menu item unless you split the menu up into separate instances of the MegaMenu.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I changed the rowitems to 5 and even tried 6 and 1 and nothing. It almost seems like it doesn't do anything. `$(document).ready(function($){
 $('#mega-menu-tut').dcMegaMenu({
  rowItems: '5',
  speed: 'fast'
 });
});` Any other suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you have two calls to $document.ready(function($){ $('#mega-menu-tut').dcMegaMenu(...  Try removing one and see if that helps.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you have two <html> tags.  There is something strange going on in your php.  You're going to have to resolve that before troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: I think I fixed the html issue. Any other suggestions/ideas?

Comment: You are still calling dcMegaMenu twice, once in the head of your file and once in the body.

Comment: Okay, I think I got them corrected now? Anything else you see wrong? Thanks again for your help!